# Printout arraylist values in a Hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a Hash map  which contains String as key and and group of arraylist obects as values

```
    Map<String,List<ReportEPVO>> myListMap = new HashMap();
```

Here Suppose the key is  2013  and  it contains  5 arraylist objects

How can i printout the values of those five objects from that  hashmap.

Comment: Get the list from map using it's key and print it...

Comment: What have you tried? Can you retrieve from a map (try) and iterate a list (try please)

Comment: sorry i am new to hashmap, i dont know how to iterate over  custom objects

Comment: @kuttanpillai check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keySet`:

```
for (String s : myListMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Current key: " + s); //Optional for better understanding
    for (ReportEPVO r : myListMap.get(s) {
        System.out.println(r.toString());
    }
}
```

The above code loops through all `List`s stored in your `Map` and in each of them through all the elements. For debug purposes you can print current key each time.

If you only want to iterate through the list stored with `key=2013` use:

```
for (ReportEPVO r : myListMap.get("2013") {
    System.out.println(r.toString());
}
```

Answering to the question from a comment. Add the following to your `ReportEPVO.java`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "FirstFieldName :" + <firstfield> + " SecondFieldName: " + <secondfield>.
}
```

In your field is String, simply put it's name. If it's a primitive (`int`, `float`, `boolean`...) put `String.valueOf(fieldName);`. Otherwise put `fieldName.toString()`.

Comment: Using `entrySet()` eliminates the need to get each item from the map.

Comment: @xenteros  yea  perfect.  one doubt it may sound dumb.  suppose i didnot  have a  tostring method in bean class(ReportEPVO)  .  how can i  print  two fields in it individually?

Comment: Well, you have toString method as all java classes have one. You might had not overriden it. Believe me. add `toString` implementation to every class you write.

Comment: @xenteros Thankz for detailed explanation . are u also familiar with jsp? because i ve another doubt..

Comment: @kuttanpillai I'm not unfortunately.

Comment: @xenteros   okkie  No Probs :)

Answer (score -1):

Using Java 8

```
String search = "300";
data.keySet().stream().filter(k -> k.equalsIgnoreCase(search)).map(k -> data.get(k)).forEach(v -> System.out.println(v));
```

Need to override toString() method in your ReportEPVO class.

Comment: Person who downvoted can you leave a comment why you did so for my knowledge of what is wrong in the code

Comment: sorry brother i am using java 7..  may be some one who dont have any idea about java8 streams downvoted you

Comment: Nowhere in your question it is mentioned that you are using Java 7 and not Java 8, I think it is wrong for anyone to downvote this because he\she doesnt have an idea about Java 8.

Comment: Yea , Some people r juz like dat.. i too gets downvotes for no reasons.